# How to rowbind two datasets with different number of columns using R

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I am trying to rowbind two `xts` datasets with different number of columns:

dataset 1:

```
    one <- structure(c(0, 0.009009, 0.008929, -0.00885, 0, -0.017857, -0.027957, 
-0.00885, -0.013393, -0.024887, 0.00232, -0.009259, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -0.017794, 0.028986, -0.007143, 0.007194, 0.021429, 
0.017483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.007968, -0.011858, 0, -0.032, -0.008264, 
0.045833, 0.015924, 0.00627, -0.003115, 0, 0.00625, 0.024845), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tclass = c("POSIXt", 
"POSIXct"), tzone = "", index = c(346406400, 346492800, 346665600, 
346924800, 347011200, 347097600), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("ALLEGHENY.POWER.SYSTEMS.INC", "ALLIED.CHEMICAL.CORP", 
    "APPLICATION.ENGR.CORP", "ALLIS.CHALMERS.CORP", "AMERICAN.ELECTR.LABS.INC", 
    "A.E.L.INDUSTRIES.INC", "AMAX.INC")))
```

dataset 2

```
   two <-  structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071429, 0.066667, 0, -0.125, 
    0, 0, 0.018182, 0.026786, 0, 0.008696, -0.025862, -0.017699, 
    0.009346, 0.006944, 0.011494, -0.045455, -0.028571, 0.014706, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS =  c("POSIXt", 
    "POSIXct"), tclass = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = "", index = c(347270400, 
    347529600, 347616000, 347702400, 347788800, 347875200), .Dim = c(6L, 
    6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A.C.S.ENTERPRISE.INC", "A.C.S.INDUSTRIES.INC", 
    "ALLEGHENY.POWER.SYSTEMS.INC", "ALLIED.CHEMICAL.CORP", "ALLIED.CORP", 
    "ALLIED.SIGNAL.INC")))
```

I have tried `rbind(one,two, by=colnames(one))` but get the following error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  data must have same number of columns to bind by row
```

essentially I would like to row bind the `xts` & add additional columns with `0` 
to handle missing columns.

Desired output:

```
DES <- structure(c(0, 0.009009, 0.008929, -0.00885, 0, -0.017857, 0.018182, 
0.026786, 0, 0.008696, -0.025862, -0.017699, -0.027957, -0.00885, 
-0.013393, -0.024887, 0.00232, -0.009259, 0.009346, 0.006944, 
0.011494, -0.045455, -0.028571, 0.014706, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.017794, 0.028986, -0.007143, 0.007194, 0.021429, 
0.017483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.007968, -0.011858, 0, -0.032, -0.008264, 0.045833, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.015924, 0.00627, -0.003115, 0, 0.00625, 0.024845, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.071429, 0.066667, 0, -0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.009346, 0.006944, 0.011494, -0.045455, -0.028571, 0.014706, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(12L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("ALLEGHENY.POWER.SYSTEMS.INC", "ALLIED.CHEMICAL.CORP", 
    "APPLICATION.ENGR.CORP", "ALLIS.CHALMERS.CORP", "AMERICAN.ELECTR.LABS.INC", 
    "A.E.L.INDUSTRIES.INC", "AMAX.INC", "A.C.S.ENTERPRISE.INC", 
    "A.C.S.INDUSTRIES.INC", "ALLIED.CHEMICAL.CORP.1", "ALLIED.SIGNAL.INC"
    )), index = c(346406400, 346492800, 346665600, 346924800, 
347011200, 347097600, 347270400, 347529600, 347616000, 347702400, 
347788800, 347875200), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXt", 
"POSIXct"), tclass = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = "")
```

Comment: Your column names are off. Do you want to rbind them asis? Or rbind the columns that share the column name?

Comment: HEllo @Avinash I would like to rbind them with those that share the same column name.

Comment: @akrun When `merge.xts()` , i get an `xts` that merges `side by side` ... in this example the only names that `one` and `two` share in common are: `ALLEGHENY.POWER.SYSTEMS.INC.` & `ALLIED.CHEMICAL.CORP.` If I `merge.xts()` it will return an object with 13 columns when the desired would be only 11 ( since they share two common header names)

Comment: @Rime Please check the solution below.  I don't understand the `11` columns.  You have only two columns that are common.

Comment: @Rime I may have missed what you are aiming for.  Could you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun I think he wants the common column names to rbind and the rest to take the values 0 where there is no value.

Comment: @Avinash that is correct, that is what i am looking for! I am working on providing a desired output

Comment: @akrun I have added the desired output! thanks for contributing

Comment: @Rime Please check the update below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a new matrix ("m1") with appropriate dimensions, ie. the `nrow` of "m1" will be the sum of rows of "one", and "two", likewise, the `ncol` is the length of all unique columns in both datasets.  Create 'name' indexes ('onenm', 'twonm') that are exclusively present in one dataset, or unique column names in both datasets ('nm2'), or the names common in both ('nm1').  By use of appropriate 'row/column' index, we can assign the elements from 'one', 'two' datasets to the newly created `xts` dataset ("xt1" created from "m1").

```
nm1 <- intersect(colnames(one), colnames(two))
onenm <-  setdiff(colnames(one), colnames(two))
twonm <- setdiff(colnames(two), colnames(one))
nm2 <- union(colnames(one), colnames(two))
m1 <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(one)+nrow(two), ncol=length(nm2), 
           dimnames=list(NULL, nm2))
xt1 <- xts(m1, order.by=c(index(one), index(two)))
xt1[index(one), onenm] <- one[,onenm]
xt1[index(two), twonm] <- two[,twonm]
xt1[,nm1] <- rbind(one[,nm1], two[,nm1])
dim(xt1)
#[1] 12 11
```

#### Update

You could also use `rbindlist` from `data.table` (or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`).  Convert the `xts` objects to "data.frame", place it in a list and use `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` option.  Convert the output ('dt1') to `xts` ('xt1'), change the "NA" values to "0".

```
 library(data.table)
 dt1 <- rbindlist(list(as.data.frame(one),
                   as.data.frame(two)), fill=TRUE)
 #or
 #library(dplyr)
 #dt1 <- bind_rows(list(as.data.frame(one), as.data.frame(two)))
 xt2 <- xts(dt1, order.by=c(index(one), index(two)))
 xt2[is.na(xt2)] <- 0
 identical(xt1, xt2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Comment: this works for binding only common names. how can i get the rest of the columns

Answer (score 1):

In addition to akrun's excellent answer, I share here a function I have been using to perform robust rbind of two xts:

```
rbind.ordered=function(x,y){

  if (is.null(x)) return(y)

  if (is.null(y)) return(x)

  diffCol = setdiff(colnames(x),colnames(y))
  if (length(diffCol)>0){
    cols=colnames(y)
    for (i in 1:length(diffCol)) y=cbind(y,NA)
    colnames(y)=c(cols,diffCol)
  }

  diffCol = setdiff(colnames(y),colnames(x))
  if (length(diffCol)>0){
    cols=colnames(x)
    for (i in 1:length(diffCol)) x=cbind(x,NA)
    colnames(x)=c(cols,diffCol)
  }
  return(rbind(x, y[, colnames(x)]))
}

rbind.ordered(one, two)
```

Then you just have to replace NA by 0 to have exactly what you want